# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException when fetching file from HTTPS Server using javax.net.UrlConnection

Tags: ssl, https, certificate, sslhandshakeexception

I implemented HTTPS client(with Certification BYPASS) as in :
http://www.nakov.com/blog/2009/07/16/disable-certificate-validation-in-java-ssl-connections/

But I get the following Exception(as attached in the image):

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:Received Fatal Alert :handshake_failure
```

[image: Screenshot_command_prompt_handshake_failure]

Not sure why I getting this error.It had worked for me before.
Also the HTTPS Server is an APACHE TOMCAT SERVER.

Is there any other way I can Ignore(bypass) HTTPS Certification?
Please let me know.

Comment: Actually I was not able to attach an image.The exception is as shown:

Comment: I've edited your question and attached the screenshot you provided.

Comment: Handshake failure is not a certification error. Thus it will not help if you disable validations. There are lots of possibilities which can cause such a handshake failure and lots of question and answers here at stackoverflow. If you don't find the cause of the problem yourself please add the necessary details to your question so that others can help you (see the other questions which got help).

Comment: I checked many answers on StackOverflow and they didnt help me fix the issue.Hence posted a new question.Thanks